# Error with if statement and for loop in method append how to solve?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The error is in the first line where the if statement is, so that if this expression is true, then this line will be added, otherwise another, how to fix it?

> SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

```
  $(".pagination_wrapper").append(
          '<ul class="new_pogination">' 
            if( data.previous_page != 0 ){
                + '<li>' + '<a href="?page=' + data.previous_page + '"' + 'onclick="sort_by_ajax()"' + 'class="prev_link"'+ '>' + '&laquo;' + '</a>' 
                + '</li>'
            }else{
                + '<li class="disabled">' + '<a class="disabled">' + '&laquo;' + '</a>' 
                + '</li>'
            };
            for ( i = 1; i < total_num; i++ ){
                if( i == current_page ){
                    + '<li class="active">' + '<a href="?page=' + i + '"' + 'onclick="sort_by_ajax()"' + '>' + i + '</a>' 
                    + '</li>'
                }else{
                    + '<li class="number_of_pagination">' + '<a href="?page=' + i + '"' + 'onclick="sort_by_ajax()"' + '>' + i + '</a>' 
                    + '</li>'
                };
            };

            if( data.next_page != total_num ){
                + '<li>' + '<a href="?page=' + data.next_page + '"' + 'onclick="sort_by_ajax()"' + 'class="next_link"' + '>' + '&raquo;' + '</a>' 
                + '</li>'
            }else{
                + '<li class="disabled">' + '<a class="disabled">' + '&raquo;' + '</a>' 
                + '</li>'
            };

            + '</ul>'
        );
```

Comment: `.append('<ul class="new_pogination">' 
            if( data.previous_page != 0 ){` - can you see the problem now?

Comment: `"a" if (a == b) { + "b" } else { + "c" } for (...) { + "d" }` - Where did you get this syntax from? O.o

Comment: @Andreas Does your comment matter in general? and how does he come close to solving my question? if you do not know how to help so at least do not bother! Not all such geniuses like you!

Comment: what's in your `data` variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this!

```js
$(".pagination_wrapper").append(function() {
      html = '<ul class="new_pogination">';
      
      if (data.previous_page != 0) {
        html += '<li>' + '<a href="?page=' + data.previous_page + '"' + 'onclick="sort_by_ajax()"' + 'class="prev_link"' + '>' + '&laquo;' + '</a>' + '</li>'
      } else {
        html += '<li class="disabled">' + '<a class="disabled">' + '&laquo;' + '</a>' + '</li>'
      };
      for (i = 1; i < total_num; i++) {
        if (i == current_page) {
          html += '<li class="active">' + '<a href="?page=' + i + '"' + 'onclick="sort_by_ajax()"' + '>' + i + '</a>' + '</li>'
        } else {
          html += '<li class="number_of_pagination">' + '<a href="?page=' + i + '"' + 'onclick="sort_by_ajax()"' + '>' + i + '</a>' +  '</li>'
        };
      };
    
      if (data.next_page != total_num) {
        html += '<li>' + '<a href="?page=' + data.next_page + '"' + 'onclick="sort_by_ajax()"' + 'class="next_link"' + '>' + '&raquo;' + '</a>' + '</li>'
      } else {
        html += '<li class="disabled">' + '<a class="disabled">' + '&raquo;' + '</a>' + '</li>'
      };
    
      html += '</ul>'
      return html;
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

This error generally means, you've messed up with the syntax.

In your code you are concatenating `+` strings to nothing, using nested `if` statements in a function variable where there should only be elements separated with a comma...

Change your approach from putting your logic inside a function parameter that expects a string, to creating a string and then passing it to `append()`. For example:

```js
// some assumptions
var total_num = 10;
var current_page = 4;
var data = {previous_page: 1, next_page: 11, current_page: 4}
// new approach

var result = '<ul class="new_pogination">';
if (data.previous_page != 0) {
    result += '<li><a href="?page=' + data.previous_page + '" onclick="sort_by_ajax()" class="prev_link">&laquo;</a></li>';
} else {
    result += '<li class="disabled"><a class="disabled">&laquo;</a></li>';
}
for (i = 1; i < total_num; i++) {
    if (i == current_page) {
        result += '<li class="active"><a href="?page=' + i + '" onclick="sort_by_ajax()">' + i + '</a></li>';
    } else {
        result += '<li class="number_of_pagination"><a href="?page=' + i + '" onclick="sort_by_ajax()">' + i + '</a></li>';
    };
}

if (data.next_page != total_num) {
    result += '<li><a href="?page=' + data.next_page + '" onclick="sort_by_ajax()" class="next_link">&raquo;</a></li>';
} else {
    result += '<li class="disabled"><a class="disabled">&raquo;</a></li>'
}


result += '</ul>';
 
    $(".pagination_wrapper").append(result);
```

```css
.active{
background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=pagination_wrapper></div>
```